# How to check block is called using rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-block

I want to check whether the block is called in my function using rspec. Below is my code:

```
class SP
  def speak(options={},&block)
    puts "speak called" 
    block.call()
    rescue ZeroDivisionError => e
  end  
end




describe SP do
 it "testing speak functionality can receive a block" do
    sp = SP.new
    def test_func 
        a = 1
    end
    sp_mock = double(sp)
    expect(sp_mock).to receive(:speak).with(test_func)
    sp.speak(test_func)
 end  
end
```

Below is my error:

```
SP testing speak functionality can receive a block
     Failure/Error: block.call()

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `call' for nil:NilClass
     # ./test.rb:9:in `speak'
     # ./test.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Could you please help. I spent lots of time in that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use one of RSpec's [yield matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-6/docs/built-in-matchers/yield-matchers):

```
describe SP do
  it "testing speak functionality can receive a block" do
    sp = SP.new
    expect { |b| sp.speak(&b) }.to yield_control
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I think Stefan provided the best answer. However I wanted to point out that you should be testing the behaviour of the code instead of implementation details.

```
describe SP do
  it "testing speak functionality can receive a block" do
    sp = SP.new
    called = false
    test_func = -> () { called = true }

    sp.speak(&test_func)

    expect(called).to eql(true)
  end  
end
```

Comment: That's what `yield_control` does, isn't it?

Comment: @Stefan It depends on what you actually want to test. In this case `.yield_with_no_args` would be the most specific test. But since `SP#speak` behaves differently depending on the passed block, you should cover those cases too. In the test setup the passed block should `raise ZeroDivisionError`.